# change padding on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check if a user has scrolled the page and if they did, I want the padding of an element to change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 if (document.body.scrollTop !== 0) {
  $(".nav-link").children().css("padding", "1em");
 };
});
```

```css
.navbar .nav-link a {
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 2em;
 color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="nav-link"><a class="page-active" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This only checks the scroll position of the page on document ready. You need to check it as the user is scrolling `$(window).scroll(function(){/*code here*/});`

Comment: What issue are you having exactly?  Is it not working as expected, causing an error?

Comment: The issue was that I was checking on page load not scroll. Thank you guys for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ...

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop !== 0) {
        $(".nav-link").children().css("padding", "1em");
    };
});
```

The wrapper will execute the if condition each time a scroll event fires.

**UPDATE**:

The scroll could actually go inside the document ready.  The document ready function just determines when the document object model has finished loading, so it is a one time event.

Comment: Ah ok I'm new to jQuery so I keep using the document ready but now I realize I should have used the scroll. Thank you very much for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo(?)
It should be:

```
#navbar .nav-link a {
```

Also I suggest you put some checks in case the user is back on top and use a css class to alter padding, eg:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
      if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
          jQuery('.nav-link').addClass("padnav");
      } else {
        jQuery('.nav-link').removeClass("padnav");
      }
  });
});
```

And then add in css:

```
#navbar .nav-link.padnav a {
  padding: 1em;
}
```